# can I ssh to Windows, start a command and let it run even when I log out?

Tags: windows, ssh

Now that Windows 10 includes an openSSH server, is there some way to start a program and let it run even when I log out?
On linux, one has screen and tmux, but what about Windows?

Notes:

- being able to re-attach to the process would be nice, but is not a requirement
- opening the program in the session of the current local user is OK as well

My use case is running scripts on my own machine from elsewhere - and since some of the scripts might take many hours to finish, I do not want to depend on keeping the SSH open. (And since the tests write results to files, it is OK to "fire and forget", i.e., not to be able to re-attach.)

I tried using PsExec from SysInternals as `psexec -i 1 start cmd.exe /k "command"` to start command in the current user's session, but this fails with `PsExec could not start start on <hastname>: The system cannot find the file specified.` ... and without `start` it does not detach from the ssh session.

Answer (score 3):

After some reading, it looks like there are two ways to run something detached from the current session: running it as a service, or using a scheduler.
Turns out the latter is relatively easy and works fine from an SSH session:

```
schtasks /create /SC ONCE /TN <task_name> /TR <full-path-to-script> /ST <HH:MM>
```

will schedule a task to run at a specified time.

Some notes:

- The script will remain in the list of scheduled tasks even after it has run, just without specified time.
- It is possible to run a scheduled task immediately, but this does **not** remove the scheduled time, i.e., it would run at HH:MM as well.
- The script is executed with `C:\WINDOWS\system32` as a working directory.

  - if it is a .bat file, one can use `pushd %~dp0` to go to the scripts directory (unlike `cd`, `pushd` works also when the directory is on another drive)
- The script will be run in a command-line window in the current session.

To run something at once, without leaving it in the list of scheduled tasks, one can use the following commands:

```
schtasks /create /SC ONCE /TN <task_name> /TR <full-path-to-script> /ST <HH:MM>
schtasks /run /TN <task_name>
schtasks /delete /TN <task_name> /F
```

Note that the last line does **not** stop the running task, only removes it from the scheduler.

After this, one can safely log off the ssh session and the script will continue to run.