# Starting application GUI on remote windows from SSH linux

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, centos

simply I'm using centOS and im connected to a windows VM using ssh. I want to open an app but with it's GUI. I tried "notepad" but it starts in the background. i can find notepad in taskmanager but cannot see it. I tried using psexec but i'm on centos and it's doesnt work. I tried running psexec after ssh and it starts the process but still no graphic.

please help thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes finally,

I created a batch file that creates a schtasks in the past, starts the task and delete it and deleting it won't stop the task . IT WORKS LIKE CHARM IM SO HAPPY.

schtasks_creater.bat:

```
schtasks /create /SC ONCE /TN task_name /TR notepad.exe /ST 00:00
schtasks /run /TN task_name
schtasks /delete /TN task_name /F
pause
```

so now from my ssh i just start the bat file and close the ssh, it continues to work even after.

big thanks to [can I ssh to Windows, start a command and let it run even when I log out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59073083/can-i-ssh-to-windows-start-a-command-and-let-it-run-even-when-i-log-out)

Comment: this is genius, nice!

if you have a space in your file path, you can do `"'D:\dir\your file path.exe'"`